# How to show Parent Excerpt on Child Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, attachment, custom-wordpress-pages

In WordPress, I have an attachment page (child page).
How to show Parent Excerpt on this page?
Because this code didn't work:

```
<?php global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>

    <?php echo get_the_excerpt( $post->post_parent ); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your help. 
I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_post_parent_id()` which will

> Returns the ID of the post’s parent.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_parent_id/

Then you can display the excerpt via `get_the_excerpt()` which will

> Retrieves the post excerpt.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/

You should get something along the line of (following is untested)

```php
<?php
echo get_the_excerpt(wp_get_post_parent_id());
//...
```

Comment: I try this code but didnt work also:

`<?php global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent ) { ?>

<?php echo get_the_excerpt(wp_get_post_parent_id()); ?>

<?php } ?>`